# Knowing when AJAX has loaded in UIWebView

Tags: ajax, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and one page has an AJAX component whose content changes when the user clicks a button. How can I know when the content has loaded inside the `UIWebView`?

Comment: So, you essentially want to execute some iOS code after an ajax request has been successful?

Comment: Yes I want to execute code after AJAX has loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do two things:

1. In your JavaScript code, have the `XMLHTTPRequest` signal that the AJAX request is complete with a custom URL:

   ```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   req.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', true);  
   req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {  
     if (req.readyState == 4) {  
        if(req.status == 200) { 
          window.location = "myspecialurl:foo"
        }
     }  
   };
   ```
2. In your native code, you'll need to implement a `UIWebView` delegate that listens for this custom URL:

   ```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
   {
     if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"myspecialurl:foo"]) {
        // Your code for when the AJAX request completes.
        return NO;
     }
     return YES;
   }
   ```

No assurances this code parses/compiles but should give you the idea how to do it.